# Define style in HAL library

Tags: stm32, hal

In HAL library used in the STM32 code we see that a style like this is used:

```
#define I2C1      ((I2C_TypeDef *) I2C1_Base)
```

- Why define is used like this?
- Why pointer type is used?
- Why isn't the star outside the parentheses?

Comment: Learn C first. Learn something about the microcontrollers. Without this answering this question is pointless

Answer (score 2):

`I2C1_Base` is declared elsewhere, and is a number as a hex literal.

`(I2C_TypeDef *)` casts the `I2C1_Base` number to a pointer to an `I2C_TypeDef`, the star needs to be within the parenthesis as it's casting to a pointer type, if it were outside then it would be a dereference and wouldn't compile.

The define is there to allow code like

```
I2C1->someRegister = 0xf00;
```

rather than needing to manually type the cast each time.